# moment js take any user input and transform to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: node.js, date, momentjs

Hello Im working on a project and part of it includes taking a date from the user and changing it to DD/MM/YYYY (taking data from url)
var urlDate = req.params;

```
var dateJSON = JSON.stringify(urlDate);
var obj = JSON.parse(dateJSON);
var final = moment(`${obj.year}-${obj.month}-${obj.day}`);
```

dont mind the day/month/year because i want the user to be able to enter 12/3/2020 and also March 3 2020

Comment: Did you try `moment.utc(userInput).format('DD/MM/YYYY')` Your `12/3/2020` is an invalid date when passed to momentjs.

Comment: I haven't tried it but won't it be incorrect as people what live far from the utc time zone ?